# How many ways to deal a 5-card hand that has 2 pairs? (order matters)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I know the answer for numbers of 5-cards hand containing 2 pairs if order does not matter is

$\binom{13}{2}$*$\binom{4}{2}$*$\binom{4}{2}$*44 = 123,552

But what if the orders a person get his/her card matter? Will it just be replacing the combinations with permutations?

Thank you.

Comment: Just multiply that answer by $5!$ to account for the number of ways to order the hand.

Comment: You are correct that the number of hands if order doesn't matter is $\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\cdot 44$.  It follows then that the number of hands if order *does* matter is just that amount times $5!$

Comment: If you insist on using a different method to count this... you can.  Pick which location in the hand the singleton card is ($5$ options), then pick which card it happens to be ($52$).  Now, the furthest left unused slot will be paired with a later slot, pick which slot it is paired with ($3$).  Pick which card fits into the left position ($48$) then pick which card goes into the paired slot ($3$ options).  Finally pick which card goes into the next unused slot and then pick it's pair ($44$ and then $3$).  This gives $5\cdot 52\cdot 3\cdot 48\cdot 3\cdot 44\cdot 3$, same as the other answer.

Comment: "*Will it just be replacing the combinations with permutations*" No, $13\frac{2}{~}\cdot 4\frac{2}{~}\cdot 4\frac{2}{~}\cdot 44$ counts the number of 5card hands where order matters with two pairs where very specifically the first two cards are paired together, the next two cards are paired together and the singleton appears at the end.